# I'm trying to apply AJAX to my tbody only not all table

Tags: php, ajax

1. I'm trying to apply Ajax to my `tbody` only not all my `table` but I can't do this. The AJAX working good if I put my complete table in page. I want to split my table header & `tbody` to be in separated page. The following code is AJAX:

   ```
   function jsQueryData() {
   var objData = {
       action: actionSplit0 + '/QueryData',
   };

   $.post(
       index_File,
       objData,
       function(data, status) {
           $('#table-container').html(data)
       },
       'html'
   )
   ```

   }
2. This is the code of my `table`. If I put the table code completely in one page the AJAX working good:

   ```
       <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover 
          main-table-h">
         <thead>
           <tr>
             <td scope="col" class="search-th">
               <input type="text" name="" value=""> <!-- for search -->
             </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <th scope="col" class="align-top">item no</th>
           </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
           <?php foreach ($allData1 as $data): ?>
             <tr>
               <td><?=$data->{2}; ?></td>
             </tr>
           <?php endforeach; ?>
         </tbody>
       </table>
   ```
3. I have tried to split the above code to be `tbody` in separate page but the data didn't come as a table but all `td`s come together.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your problem, you want to set your thead static but your tbody by AJAX, if yep,

HTML:

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover 
   main-table-h">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td scope="col" class="search-th">
        <input type="text" name="" value=""> <!-- for search -->
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" class="align-top">item no</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JS (JQUERY):

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'result.php',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(response){
        var tableData=$("table").ediTable({
            json:{
                body:response
            },
            editable:false // if you do not want it editable.
        })
        //and if you want to send JSON data of table you can :
        jsonData=tableData.data();
        // now you can send jsonData to PHP via ajax ...
    }
});
```

Ref Lib:https://github.com/OxiGen1001/ediTable/

if i misunderstood your problem please let me know!

Answer (score -1):

You will need to return ajax results as json.
I did not see your table and database structure so let me create a table as follows and insert values into it for purpose 
of testing

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Insert Statetments for testing

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username`, `name`, `email`, `timestamp`) VALUES
(1, 'nancy1', 'Nancy moore  ', 'nancyfake@gmail.com', '2018-11-16 05:02:35'),
(2, 'tony1', 'tony moore    ', 'tonyfake@gmail.com', '2018-11-16 05:08:23');
```

Here is a Re-write of your **index.php** reflecting ajax/jquery codes

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>

       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'result.php',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(response){
            var len = response.length;
            for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                var id = response[i].id;
                var username = response[i].username;
                var name = response[i].name;
                var email = response[i].email;

                var tr_str = "<tr>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + (i+1) + "</td>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + username + "</td>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + name + "</td>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + email + "</td>" +
                    "</tr>";

                $("#userTable tbody").append(tr_str);
            }

        }
    });
});
</script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <table id="userTable" border="1" >
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="5%">S.no</th>
                        <th width="20%">Username</th>
                        <th width="20%">Name</th>
                        <th width="30%">Email</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**config.php**

Remember to edit database credentials to suit yours

```
<?php

$host = "localhost"; /* Host name */
$user = "root"; /* User */
$password = ""; /* Password */
$dbname = "your-db-name here"; /* Database name */

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password,$dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$con) {
 die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

**result.php**

```
<?php

include "config.php";

$return_arr = array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY NAME";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $id = $row['id'];
    $username = $row['username'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $email = $row['email'];

    $return_arr[] = array("id" => $id,
                    "username" => $username,
                    "name" => $name,
                    "email" => $email);
}

// Encoding array in JSON format
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

Thats all. Let me know how it goes

Comment: can i send JSON data to php variable then use foreach ?

Comment: must  you loop using for each. Ajax  has an  approach. The best bet is the solution  i created for you okay.  this is the title of your question "I'm trying to apply AJAX to my tbody only not all table". If you are looking foreach approach, you have to rephrase your question and see who helps okay